# How can I wake up the Debian 11 screen (Wayland) from the command line? (Deactivate "blank screen")

Tags: debian, wayland

I've set up an MQTT program to control my Debian server. I have a motion sensor in my server closet, and I want the screen to come on automatically when I walk into the closet (even before I move the mouse or touch the keyboard.) I still want the screen to turn off after 5 minutes of inactivity.

I am able to run `sudo vbetool dpms off` to turn off the monitor, and `sudo vbetool dpms on` to turn it on again. However, I noticed that I can still access the server via VNC, even if the monitor is off.

I have these Power Saving options in Settings, and the "Blank Screen" setting seems to be breaking everything:

[image: Debian Power settings]

If the "blank screen" is activated, `sudo vbetool dpms on` will turn on the screen, but the screen stays blank. I can also no longer connect via VNC.

How can I deactivate Debian's "blank screen" from the command line? Is there something I can run to simulate wiggling the mouse? Or should I disable the "blank screen" setting and use something else to turn off the screen after inactivity? (xscreensaver?)

I am using Wayland, so I can't seem to run any `xset` commands I've found online or other things for Xorg.

Here's all the processes I have that contain "session":

```
# ps ax | grep session
  24510 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
  27420 ?        Sl     0:00 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]
  27451 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
  27475 ?        S<l    0:00 /usr/bin/pipewire-media-session
  27480 tty3     Ssl+   0:00 /usr/libexec/gdm-wayland-session /usr/bin/gnome-session
  27487 tty3     Sl+    0:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd
  27541 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-ctl --monitor
  27546 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd-service --session=gnome
  27708 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
  28262 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto session
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a reliable solution. There is a command-line tool called "ydotool" which you can use to move the mouse or send keystrokes.

The version that you can install using apt is too old and very buggy, so I needed to clone it from GitHub and compile it from source. Here's all the commands I ran to do that:

```
git clone https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool
cd ydotool
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j `nproc`
sudo make install
cp ydotool.service /etc/systemd/system/
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable ydotool.service
systemctl start ydotool.service
```

Now you will have a `ydotool` command that you can use.

Here's a simple "wiggle mouse" script that I wrote to wake up the screen:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu
ydotool mousemove --absolute -- 355 0
sleep 0.1
ydotool mousemove --absolute -- 350 0
```

This works well for me, and I can continue using the built-in "blank screen" feature in the Debian Power Saving settings.